# HTTP methods on Public API vs Routes

Tags: javascript, web-services, api, rest, http

Github and Twitter use different HTTP methods on their public API and site routes to complete the same action.

For example, to remove a star using Github API

```
DELETE /user/starred/:owner/:repo
```

But on their site they call

```
POST https://github.com/jshint/jshint/unstar
```

Why doesn't this request use a similar approach as the public API based on the DELETE method?

Comment: for deleting an object in rest api we commonly uses the delete http method

Comment: post for create an object and put for update an object.

Comment: But why they use post to unstar in the site?

Comment: it's just depend on the developer, i don't understand why they put POST http method instead of PUT or DELETE

Comment: you can take look at this simple example http://micheltriana.com/2013/09/30/http-verbs-in-a-rest-web-api/

Comment: also you can take a look at this if you want to go deeper. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340